# How to give specific range to datetime-local input type?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, cordova

Working on **Phonegap** application, it requires to provide specific date range (for example, User should be able to pick only future dates up to 10 days from now).

Testing application into iPad. I have tried with **min** and **max** attributes but not working.

```
<span class="field_text">Preferred Date &amp; Time</span>
<input id="checkout_datetime" type="datetime-local" class="text_box_cnt" required="required"/>
```

Please help...

Comment: The `min` and `max` attributes are the solution. Show how you have tried to use them. Also note that `datetime-local` is poorly supported and highly debated (in discussions about HTML specifications).

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm using `date` input, but it's basically the same issue that you.

Comment: Here is a workaround for Cordova (not PG Build).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943511/limit-the-selectable-dates-in-native-datepicker-in-ios-phonegap-app/26086166#26086166

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it's the first result that came up for me when Googling, so I wanted to leave a proper answer.

The `min` and `max` attributes [are indeed the ones to use to restrict input to a given range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#additional_attributes):

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time"
       name="meeting-time" value="2018-06-12T19:30"
       min="2018-06-07T00:00" max="2018-06-14T00:00">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use date instead of datetime-local.Here is an example

```
<input id="checkout_datetime" type="date" min="2014-03-20" max="2014-03-30" class="text_box_cnt" />
```

Reference by http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer....I think min & max is the solution, but it is not working in phonegap application