# Limit the selectable dates in native datepicker in iOS Phonegap App

Tags: html, ios, cordova, datepicker

I'm developing an App for **iOS** with **Phonegap Build** and I'm using an input data type to call the native datepicker (without problems) and select some dates, but I want limit the selectable dates.

I've tried with the `min` and `max` attributes of the input, but are ignored. Tested on iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Here is my code:

```
<input id="fecha-buscar" type="date" min="2014-01-01" max="2014-12-31" value="2014-01-01">
```

I found [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627117/how-to-give-specific-range-to-datetime-input-type), but without answer.

Any idea how solve this? Can be fixing the `min` and `max` attributes of `<input type="date">` or other way but calling the **native datepicker** of iOS.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I faced with this issue also. Jabel, did you find the solution? I feel like a datepicker plugin from cordova is a single way

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, using native cordova (not pg build), I thought I'd share this work around.

In MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
         :
    /* add this somewhere */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_pickerViewWillBeShown:) name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
         :
}

- (void)_pickerViewWillBeShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    [self performSelector:@selector(_resetPickerViewBackgroundAfterDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

-(void)_resetPickerViewBackgroundAfterDelay
{
    UIPickerView *pickerView = nil;
    for (UIWindow *uiWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        for (UIView *uiView in [uiWindow subviews]) {
            pickerView = [self _findPickerView:uiView];
        }
    }

    if (pickerView){
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]    initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
        //set for today at 8 am
        [components setHour:8];
        NSDate *todayAtTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
        //set max at now + 60 days
        NSDate *futureDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60 * 24 * 60];

//        [pickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [pickerView.superview setValue:@"15" forKey:@"minuteInterval"];
        [pickerView.superview setValue:futureDate forKey:@"maximumDate"];
        [pickerView.superview setValue:todayAtTime forKey:@"minimumDate"];
    }
}

-(UIPickerView *) _findPickerView:(UIView *)uiView
{
        if ([uiView isKindOfClass:[UIPickerView class]] ){
            return (UIPickerView*) uiView;
        }

        if ([uiView subviews].count > 0) {
            for (UIView *subview in [uiView subviews]){
                UIPickerView* view = [self _findPickerView:subview];
                if (view)
                    return view;
            }
        }
        return nil;
}
```

Tested with iOS 6/7, Cordova 3.5, devices/sim

Comment: I'm compiling my App with Phonegap Build not Cordova, how can I use this code?

Comment: I think you would have to develop and submit a plugin for their consideration. Not sure if they allow custom plugins. Kinda why I don't use PG Build...been using this work around for a couple of years

Answer (score 0):

I just found a datepicker plugin for phonegap/cordova and it has options for min & max values.
https://github.com/sectore/phonegap3-ios-datepicker-plugin/tree/ios7